# Input::all() empty after FormData object passed

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-5, form-data

I have a form that I need to process before it's submitted. The form has several `text` and `radio` inputs, as well as a `file` one. I'm using **jQuery** to pass the form data:

```
$button.on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var formData = new FormData($('.js-my-form')[0]);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/get-data',
        data: formData,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    }).done(function(response) {
        // handle response
    });

});
```

Then, in **Laravel** controller:

```
$input = Input::all() // <- EMPTY ARRAY
```

No idea why `Input` comes empty. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using a GET to send a request with `enctype = multipart/form-data`. When you use a native FormData object this is the format that you get by default. You can read [how to send the form's data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)

> using the POST method and setting the enctype attribute to application/x-www-form-urlencoded (default);
>
> using the POST method and setting the enctype attribute to text/plain;
>
> using the POST method and setting the enctype attribute to multipart/form-data;
>
> using the GET method (in this case the enctype attribute will be ignored).

So if you set your requesto to a GET the content of your form present in the body of the request will be ignored. The enctype attribute is what tells the server how to process your request. This is why you should use POST.

Note that when you write

```
contentType: false,
processData: false
```

you are telling jQuery that do not mess with the data you are passing and leave your native Formdata object untouched. This will cause the enctype to be set automatically.

Answer (score 0):

First i suggest use a type 'POST' to pass your data at your method and second, try serialize the form data

```
 $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/get-data', /*Route laravel*/
        data: formData.serialize(),
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    }).done(function(response) {
        // handle response
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, I already figured out what messes the code. Plus, `serialize` won't give me the file input data.

Comment: You can not call formData.serialize(). the native FormData object does not contain a serialize property. You can use data: formData and this will work

Answer (score 0):

So, I could not find any resource to confirm this, but it seems `FormData` won't work with `GET` type - at least when using jQuery's `$.ajax()` function.

Changed `GET` to `POST` - and the form input is getting to the Laravel controller with no problems.

Not sure I like it, thought, as I'm actually not `POST`ing anything, but `GET`ting information I need. Anyways, it works.